# How can I use floating images with CKEditor in django-cms?

Tags: html, django, ckeditor, django-cms

I'm using django-cms with djangocms_text_ckeditor and cmsplugin_filer_image.

Whenever I insert an image in a text block on a page and choose "Style > Styled Image (left)", the image appears as I want it to be in the WYSIWYG editor (that is, floating on the left with the text floating at its right).

But on the published page, the image is not floating, it is just left-aligned between two paragraphs.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem yesterday. What I found after doing some research is that for the cmsplugin-filer plugins you have to create templates for the way you want them to be rendered. E.g., say I want an image to be rendered floating left with some padding and margin (like a box). I would do the following:

1. Create a css file in my app with the styles I want
2. In my templates folder create cmsplugin_filer_image/plugins/image/boxed.html. Basically boxed.html is like the default.html file you can find in the plugin code but with the css classes I want to apply to the image
3. Add a reference to my css file in boxed.html

For this to work you have to add this code to your settings.py

```
CMSPLUGIN_FILER_IMAGE_STYLE_CHOICES = (
    ('default', 'Default'),
    ('boxed', 'Boxed'),
)
CMSPLUGIN_FILER_IMAGE_DEFAUL_STYLE = 'boxed'
```

Once this is done, when you add an image to CKEditor you can select the style you want the image to be rendered.

Hope this help!

Here is the source for the plugin and the explanation by its author https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer#customisation